# Synchronize lightbox with Jssor gallery

Tags: gallery, lightbox, jssor, synchronize

I have a Jssor gallery with active autoplay in the options. When I put the mouse in the gallery, the automatic playback stops. That's right.
I also have a light box to see the images in real size, but when I have the lightbox open, the images in the back gallery change. I would like that when the light box is opened, the background gallery is also paused. And even change the item when passing the image in the lightbox.
Would it be possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Please call `jssor_slider_instance.$Pause()` before popup the lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jssor.

```
//Pause the gallery when we access the Lightbox
$('#gallery_img1').click(function(){
  jssor_1_slider.$Pause();
});
//Go to the next image in the gallery when you pass in Lightbox
$('#next-button').on('click', function(){
  if (jssor_1_slider.$CurrentIndex() < (jssor_1_slider.$SlidesCount()-1)){
    jssor_1_slider.$Next();
  }
});   
//Go to the previous image in the gallery when passing in Lightbox
$('#previous-button').on('click', function(){
  if (jssor_1_slider.$CurrentIndex() > 0){
    jssor_1_slider.$Prev();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello Jssor, 
I have a problem with this solution. Apparently it works well, but the following error arises: when I click on the gallery image, the lightbox opens, I navigate to the last image and close the lightbox, and the jssor gallery is also in the last image (all correct). I click again on the image and the lightbox reopens, I navigate to the first image and close the lightbox, and the gallery jssot is in the first image but immediately changes to the last image. I should stay in the first image, but I do not understand why it is changed.
Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: @jssor Do you know something about this?